# Update Statement with a order by and where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, sql-order-by

Can someone please help I keep on getting this error:
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.
This is the query I'm using:

```
UPDATE  SMS 
SET idx30 = 'New' 
WHERE idx30 in 
(
  SELECT * 
  FROM SMS 
  WHERE idx30 IS NULL
    AND (idx15 = 'Del' OR idx15 = 'Fail')
    AND Idx13 <> '1'
    AND Idx7 >= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) 
  ORDER BY idx7 DESC
);
```

Comment: which db you are really using  .. ????  you tag mysql  but  your error messages  seems for Sql Server ..

Comment: Sorry should be only sql

Comment: I cannot know why do you need the ORDER BY statement in your query

Comment: What **effect** are you expecting that `ORDER BY` clause to have? An `IN` asks "does the expression on the left appear anywhere in the set on the right?". How would changing the "order" of the set on the right change the answer to that question?

Comment: (And even once that's fixed, it's clear from the subquery that `SMS` contains multiple columns - so the `SELECT *` is going to trip things up too - what *column* did you want the `IN` to compare?)

Comment: Please tell us what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You are trying to ORDER BY clause in subquery which is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You could just update the rows which match the criteria. No need for the subquery or the ORDER BY.

```
UPDATE  SMS 
SET idx30 = 'New' 
WHERE (idx15 = 'Del' OR idx15 = 'Fail')
  AND Idx13 <> '1'
  AND Idx7 >= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

Two correction in the query are:

1. Order error is coming because of order by clause inside your query which is syntax error.
2. you have written * in sub query which will again throw error of

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.